# Java Apache Ftp retrieveFile not downloading big file

Tags: java, apache, ftp, apache-commons, apache-commons-net

I'm trying to **retrieve file(.dat)** with size of **1 GB**, but, after retrieving some bytes from server it shows **no connection of Ftp** Server but, this program throws no error and hangs, my code **runs perfactly fine for small file** but, for big file it fails
code is as follows

```
//Ftp Connection  
ftpClient.connect(server, port);  
ftpClient.login(username, password);  
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();  
ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

//File Downloading
File downloadFile = new File(savePath);
OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile));
isFileDownloaded= ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFilePath, outputStream);`
```